# combine 2tables with duplicated hits in R

Tags: r, duplicates

i have the following problem:

I have a file looking like this:

```
table1
Nb_ID   Ly_ID
NbID1   ID1
NbID2   ID2
NbID3   ID3
NbID4   ID4
...
```

And a second file:

```
table2
CODE    NAME    IDENTIFIER  DESCRIPTION
1.1.1.1 Name1   ID1         DESCRIPTION1
1.1.1.2 Name2   ID2         DESCRIPTION2
25.7.8  Name3   ID2         DESCRIPTION3
...
```

I need to combine both tables with the property Ly_ID=IDENTIFIER. At the end it should look like this:

```
table3
Nb_ID Ly_ID CODE    NAME  DESCRIPTION
NbID1 ID1   1.1.1.1 Name1 DESCRIPTION1
NbID2 ID2   1.1.1.2 Name2 DESCRIPTION2
NbID2 ID2   25.7.8  Name3 DESCRIPTION3
```

My problem:
It is possible that table1.Ly_ID can have more than one hit in table2.IDENTIFIER
So I get the warnings: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length.

My question:
How can I combine these two tables when there are 2+ hits for one table1.Ly_ID in table2.IDENTIFIER.
In this case it is necessary that table1.Nb_ID has to be duplicated into table3.Nb_ID. And this is what I dont know how to do.

I have tried this:

```
table3<-cbind(table1[,1],table1[,2],table2$CODE[table1[,2]==table2$IDENTIFIER],...)
```

Comment: Look at the `merge` function. I guess that a simple `merge(table2,table1,by.x="IDENTIFIER",by.y="Ly_ID")` should do the trick.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to keep IDs 3 and 4 even though they have no data in `table2`?

Comment: @nicola thanks. your tip worked well. at the beginning i was scared why i got 50k X 50k=>5,5kk rows, but there were empty IDs in both tables. so R merged empty IDs together and generated exponentially many rows. after deleting everything looks fine :)   and richard, yes i wanted to keep all IDs in table1, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

One way with `dplyr` would be:

```
library(dplyr)

#df1 is your table 1, and df2 is your table 2
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("Ly_ID" = "IDENTIFIER"))

#  Ly_ID Nb_ID    CODE  NAME  DESCRIPTION
#1   ID1 NbID1 1.1.1.1 Name1 DESCRIPTION1
#2   ID2 NbID2 1.1.1.2 Name2 DESCRIPTION2
#3   ID2 NbID2  25.7.8 Name3 DESCRIPTION3
```

Comment: @RichardScriven That works too if you want to keep NAs.